# Looking for a standalone library for handling HTTP cookies on a personal container in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, standards

Do you know if a Javascript library to handle cookies exists, that is mature and can work without a browser? In other words I only want the cookie logic that is included in the web browsers and HTTP clients and following the current standards, and the cookies are stored and retrieved from a private store.

I think the library can only contain get/set methods. The set method set cookies that came from the "Set-Cookie" HTTP header and the get method returns a list of cookies to send in the "Cookie" header for a specific host (or domain). The get method would need to receive a host as a parameter too, since return an error or something if a host is specifying cookies for another domain. There are more details about cookies that can be nice to have.

I saw questions like [Is there an equivalent to the Apache HTTP Client in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316377/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-apache-http-client-in-javascript) but the answer works and sets the cookie within a browser and not in a specific container.

**Note:** I looked into https://github.com/jed/cookies/blob/master/lib/cookies.js , it is the closer library that matches the question right now. The most important issue against it is that there is not a getter for a domain: imagine you want to return all cookies for the yahoo.com domain, this logic is not part of the library and it is one of the most important features for a cookie library to decide which cookies to send in an HTTP request.

Comment: So essentially you want an app that can query a Web site and do nothing but store and retrieve its cookies?

Comment: From the functional aspect yes. It can receive cookies from many web sites and when a connection is established can decide which cookies to sent based on the standards.

Comment: Does libcurl's cookie jar do what you want?

Comment: @Barmar it is not written in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a library that answers my question: [CookieJar for Node](https://github.com/bmeck/node-cookiejar) (not bound to HTTP requests). Take into account that the @Barmar comment was related to [cookie jar on libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html).

I found the lib using the following query: *site:github.com cookies lib domain secure*

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Cookies.js](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies) yet? It claims to be client-side AND cross-browser.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it works. The code is using with the document.cookie and even if there is a cache inside the code assigning a cookie document.cookie does many things internally (in the browser) that are not handled by this library.